# Data tables sorting, with a href

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I'm trying to use .dataTable for sorting, and it works fine, except for a column that holds numbers that I used the href tag on them.
without the tag, the sorting works fine, but when I use the tag it seems to sort them as strings:

```
1
2
3
11
14
21
```

becomes:

```
1
11
14
2
21
etc.
```

this is the code:

```
        $('#datatableme').dataTable({
            "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
            "aoColumns": [
                         null,
                         null,
                         null,
                         null,
                         null,
                         null,
                         null
                     ],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 40,
            "bStateSave": false
        });
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lee (and people in the office :) ), I found the answer, and this is how it's done:

```
            $('#datatableme').dataTable({
            "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
            "aoColumns": [
                         null,
                         null,
                         null,
                         null,
                         { "iDataSort": 6 },
                         null,
                         { "bVisible": false }
```

The last column is the same as the one that i wanted to organize, but without the href tag.
here is the table:

```
                                        <td>
                                            <a href=""><%=arr("num")%></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%=arr("Name")%>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%=arr("num")%>
                                        </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `sType` parameter of whichever column in your listing to `html`. Something like this:

```
"aoColumns": [
    { "sType": "html" },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
],
```

This means that any HTML within the cell will be disregarded in the sort function.

Here is a working example from the [DataTables documentation](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html_sort.html).

Answer (score 1):

2 options.

1. Use the custom sorting plugin found here: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting which will allow you to define a sort type of "html with numbers", which strips html tags then sorts the remaining data by numeric value rather than string
2. Create a ghost/dummy column next to your column, set it to invisible in the column definitions, then use "iDataSort" to specify that sorting should be done on this "hidden" column, when you click the visible column sort button

Comment: 1. didn't work. it crashed.
2. How do you do that? i think there is a simpler way... :\

Comment: Did you set it up correctly? Not sure if the plugin is kept up to date with the versions of datatables. I've never used it, i usually do a ghost column or just have click handlers instead of anchor tags

Answer (score 1):

There is an alt solution for that ... you can simply add and ID or NAME on A tag, before the HREF ...

For example, I was sorting my table by name ... and when I put the

```
<a href="link">John Doe</a>
```

the DataTable screwed up with everything ...

So I just add NAME before HREF ... looking like this:

```
<a name="John Doe" href="link">John Doe</a>
```

Did work for me.
So I believe you can try something like:

```
<a name="1" href="link">1</a>
<a name="3" href="link">3</a>
<a name="2" href="link">2</a>
```

DataTable should sort this normaly.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables will attempt to automatically detect the data types that your table contains, allowing it to accurately sort and filter this data

Note that prior to DataTables 1.7 the HTML type was not automatically detected, and it was necessary to specify the sType for the column

this may help you

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/html_sort.html